# Please help me about problem in my git branch

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-branch, git-pull

I can pull from another branch, but the data from another branch not updated in my branch. When i try pulled manually git pull branch_andy2 production it shows error like this :

fatal: 'branch_andy2' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the remote repository and re-add it.

follow the below command to remove

```
git remote -v

git remote remove <present remote name>
```

after remove add back using the below command

```
git remote add <remote-name> <githuburl>
```

Then do this:

```
git push origin master
git pull
```

I hope this answer is helped you

Comment: It's same, I can't pull from my other branch.
It works, pull says already up to date, but my data not updated

Comment: did you log in to your GitHub account via the command line? to check use this command `git config --list` , there you can see `user.email` and `user.name` . check you logged into the correct account.